# Anti-aliasing in R graphics under Windows (as per Mac)

Tags: r, antialiasing

is there a way to plot anti-aliased graphics from the Windows version of R? As you can see from the two versions below the Mac version of R prints graphics anti aliased....
[image: Mac Version]

....whereas while the Windows version anti-aliases text, it does not anti-alias the actual graphic, as can be seen from the riser points, and the grid:
[image: Windows Version]

Here is the code by the way:

```
library(scatterplot3d) 
attach(mtcars) 
s3d <-scatterplot3d(wt,disp,mpg, pch=16, highlight.3d=TRUE,
  type="h", main="3D Scatterplot")
fit <- lm(mpg ~ wt+disp) 
s3d$plane3d(fit)
```

I need the highest quality possible, for web page publication. I am running Windows 7 and pulling data from RBloomberg, which only works under Windows.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is likely to depend on details of the rendering engine on each platform, which could be hard to modify. My suggestions (untested, for lack of time and access to Windows):

- install the `cairoDevice` package and use `Cairo_png()`.  According to the documentation:

> ```
>  This functions the same as any other R graphics device. You may
>  use the conventional plot commands and expect essentially the same
>  output, except that everything is anti-aliased (similar to other
>  vector-based devices like Quartz). Alpha-blending is supported, as
>  is enhanced interactivity via ‘getGraphicsEvent’. The device
>  should work the same across all supported platforms (Mac, Windows,
>  and Linux).
> ```

- Render the PNG at a much higher resolution (or output data from R as PDF) and use ImageMagick (`convert`) or some other tool to get the  anti-aliased version you need.

Comment: You can also output as SVG with Cairo which may provide superior output.

Comment: I have (finally) got this working. But is there any way to save files or copy and paste, from the screen image, like one can with the standard device? Thanks.

Comment: Once cairoDevice is installed, you can simply call Cairo() for a plot window that is anti-aliased under MS Windows.

Answer (score 15):

Installing `cairoDevice` is no longer necessary for using Cairo with `png` devices. You can now specify `type='cairo'` when opening the device. Compare the following:

```
png('test1.png', 500, 500)
s3d <- scatterplot3d(wt,disp,mpg, pch=16, highlight.3d=TRUE,
                     type="h", main="3D Scatterplot")
fit <- lm(mpg ~ wt+disp) 
s3d$plane3d(fit)
dev.off()
```

[image]

```
png('test2.png', 500, 500, type='cairo')
s3d <- scatterplot3d(wt,disp,mpg, pch=16, highlight.3d=TRUE,
                     type="h", main="3D Scatterplot")
fit <- lm(mpg ~ wt+disp) 
s3d$plane3d(fit)
dev.off()
```

[image]

I'm running Win 8.1, and 64-bit R 3.2.2.

Answer (score 9):

Use a vector device such as pdf. First make sure you have that capability and so not surprisingly the `capabilities` function is what to check. If you do have pdf then just do this:

```
pdf(file="out_graph.pdf")
s3d <-scatterplot3d(wt,disp,mpg, pch=16, highlight.3d=TRUE,
  type="h", main="3D Scatterplot")
fit <- lm(mpg ~ wt+disp) 
s3d$plane3d(fit)
dev.off()
```

An alternative for web output might be the png() graphics device. It gets high marks for compactness and web browser compatibility although it is a raster format.

Comment: @Joris ... I thought the SO interface might have chosen a format on its own. I don't think it takes my pdf's and keeps them in that format when I upload them. (But I could be in error here.)

Comment: The OP said he needs them for web display, so he probably needs a raster format.

Comment: I would be lazy and make a pdf then use ImageMagick to convert that to a high-res png.

Comment: @DWin : I would have thought so too, but the difference between the upper plot and the lower is apparent, and both are png.

Comment: @ Joris. Right. So the problem is with the default output of the screen graphics device in Win7. He needs to coerce the format to something else or to apply settings that improve the resolution.