# ggplot2: blurry facet labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, facet

When I save a `ggplot` figure -- regardless of whether I use `ggsave()` or e.g. `png()` -- the facet labels come out looking blurry. For example, the following code produces a facet label 'F' that looks like the picture below, with coloration on the outer pixels of the text raster.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1, y=1, f='F'), aes(x, y)) +
    facet_grid(. ~ f)
ggsave('foo.png')
```

[image]

Thanks in advance for any advice!

PS -- As per @Brian's request, I'm updating this post to note that I'm using a Windows machine.

PPS -- I'm updating my post again, this time to clarify that I plan to insert the figure into Word. So as per suggestion #4 from [this post](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/01/10-tips-for-making-your-r-graphics-look-their-best.html) that @Masoud pointed me to, I would like to use a pixel-based format (e.g. PNG) rather than a vector-based format (e.g. PDF).

Comment: What about the axis labels or other text? What if you use `ggsave("foo.pdf")`? What about `ggsave("foo.png", dpi = 600)`?

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/high-resolution-figures-in-r/

Comment: https://danieljhocking.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/high-resolution-figures-in-r/

Comment: @Brian, I agree that the PDF looks great, but a PDF won't work for my particular purpose; I need a png/jpeg/tiff that I can insert into Word. Sorry for not being clear about this in my original post.

Comment: @Masoud, I tried using alternative functions and increasing the resolution as suggested in the posts you linked to, but the coloration on the outer pixels of the text raster persists.

Comment: @Mariel, could you update your post with information about the operating system of your computer? Also try adding a different font to the labels to see what changes that makes.

Comment: Thanks, @Brian. I updated my post to clarify that I'm working on a Windows machine. I didn't have any luck with the different font.

Comment: As @baptiste noted below, this is an anti-aliasing issue, which is why I asked about different fonts and your platform. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6023887

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try disabling antialiasing

default (quartz):
[image]

`ggsave('foo.png', antialias="none")`:
[image]

Comment: To add to this answer, you can find the options in `?png` and `?windows`, which are passed onto `ggsave`.

Comment: Thanks @baptiste!

Answer (score 1):

Try save as vector-based format like `.eps`:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1, y=1, f='F'), aes(x, y)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ f)
ggsave('foo.eps', device = 'eps')
```

Alternatively you can save the image as a .jpeg and increase the Dots Per Inch with option dpi.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1, y=1, f='F'), aes(x, y)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ f)
ggsave('foo.jpeg', device = 'jpeg',dpi = 5000)
```

There are multiple higher quality formats, you can check the specifics by running `?ggsave`

Comment: Thanks @giac_man. I agree that the PDF looks great, but a PDF won't work for my particular purpose; I need a png/jpeg/tiff that I can insert into Word. Sorry for not being clear about this in my original post.

Comment: You can choose from different output formats. For example .eps can be inserted as an image in Word. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the vector-based graphics to play nicely with Word. As per suggestion #4 from [this post](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/01/10-tips-for-making-your-r-graphics-look-their-best.html) that @Masoud pointed me to, I would prefer to use a pixel-based format if possible.

Comment: I'm afraid this is an issue related to Word not R at this point. I think I have answered your original question. If you want publication quality images you should use either pdf or vectorised images.

Comment: Thanks, @giac_man. I'll update the post to clarify that I plan to embed the figure in a Word document. Sorry again for not being clear about this originally. I don't think this is a Word issue though. If I open the png produced by ggsave() or png() directly, the coloration on the outer pixels of the text raster is visible, even though I'm not using Word to open the figure.

Comment: I think @baptiste answer is the best, however I also update my answer with an alternative solution that seems to solve the issue by improving dpi.