# GGplot2: How do I avoid blurry output of scatterplot and blurred text?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, scatter-plot

I have a large dataframe consisting of fires that occurred during different years, I have successfully graphed these in a scatterplot using ggplot 2, however all of my text in the plot has a strange coloured halo around it.
[Here is an example of the text up close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqZVa.png).

[Here is an example of what the final product looks like from far away](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNzuc.png)

Also if I try to save it as a PDF, only the points show up in the pdf, no labels, 
axis, or legend.

I have seen this issue before when using geom_text() and have been able to resolve it by adding `geom_text(..., check_overlap = TRUE)`. However, in this case I specify all of my text within a theme using element_text(), and cannot seem to find an answer as to why this strange colouring is occurring.

Here is a sample of my data:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(REP_DATE = c("1988-05-02", "2015-04-18", "1981-06-19", "2009-06-18"),
                      YEAR = c("1988", "2015", "1981", "2009"),
                      CAUSE = c("L", "H", "L", "H"),
                      CALC_HA=c("2350.18324","2350.18324", "1825.316641", "2296.424534"))
```

As well as my original code to create the plot:

```r
#load your packages
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(dplyr)
library(anytime)
library(PCICt)
library(lubridate)
library(forcats)
library(ggExtra)

# first we need to make it a PCICt object
#set Rep_date as a date
data$REP_DATE <- as.Date(data$REP_DATE, "%Y-%m-%d")
data$YDAY <- anydate(yday(data$REP_DATE))
class(data$YDAY)

#subset just the data with H and L
data_H_L <- data[data$CAUSE=="H" | data$CAUSE=="L",]

p<-ggplot(data_H_L, aes(x = YDAY,                                            #set x and Y Axis
                        y = YEAR, colour=CAUSE, size=CALC_HA)) +             #set the colour and size 
  scale_y_reverse()+                        # reverse Y scale to get the years at the top to bottom order
  guides(size=FALSE)+                                                        #remove size legend 
  geom_point(alpha=0.2) +                                                    #set the transparency 
  #scale_color_brewer(type="qual", palette="Dark2")+                         #change the colours here, Dark2 looks good
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("#0195D6", "#E66407"),
                      name  ="Fire Cause",
                      breaks=c("H", "L"),
                      labels=c("Human", "Lightning"))+                       #specify colours using unique colour combo
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month",date_labels="%b")+  
  #scale_colour_discrete(values=c("#F93800", "#FFB500"),
  removeGrid(x=TRUE, y=FALSE)+                                               # remove x grid
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),                      #set plot background colour
        panel.background=element_rect(fill="black"))+                        #set panel colour
  scale_size_continuous(range=c(1.75,10))+                                   #set scale for size of circles                                     
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=4, alpha=1)))        #set size of circles in legend

pp<-p+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", colour="white", size=10, family="sans"),  #set X axis text
             axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", colour="white", size=10, family="sans"), #set y axis text
             axis.ticks = element_blank(),
             panel.grid.major.y = element_line(linetype="solid",size=1),#set y axis line width
             plot.title = element_text(color="white", size=14, face="bold", hjust=0.5, family="sans"),#set main title
             plot.subtitle = element_text(color="white", size=12, face="bold", hjust=0.5,family="sans"),#set subtitle 
             axis.title.x = element_blank(),                                       #set x axis title details
             axis.title.y = element_blank(),                                       #set y axis title details
             legend.text = element_text(colour="white", size=10, face="bold",family="sans"), #set legend axis title details
             legend.background = element_rect(fill="black", size=1, linetype="solid", colour= "white"), #set legend background
             legend.title = element_text(colour="white", size=12, face="bold",family="sans"),
             legend.title.align = 0.5,                                      #set legend title
             legend.key=element_blank())                              #set legend key to blank to get rid of background around dot
ggsave("test2.jpg", units="in", width=10, height=7, dpi=300)
ggsave(pp, filename = "Full_Point_Density.tiff", dpi = 900, type = "cairo",width = 10, height = 7, units = "in")
```

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Your data example is not matching your code for plotting (e.g. df1 versus data_H_L and x = YDAY which is not mention in the df1). Can you edit your question to make your example reproducible ?

Comment: Yes, sorry that was from my original data, I'll edit now!

Comment: Have you tried saving the plot output as SVG? This just looks like raster image anti-aliasing artifacts to me.

Comment: I am not familiar with the SVG format, however this did seem to work! The main issue is I need it to be in either a Tiff, JPEG or PDF format, at the highest quality possible. But you have definitely put me on the right track thank you!

Comment: PDF is also fine, since it is a vector graphics device (e.g. infinite zoom without quality loss). TIFF and JPEG are raster images, so likely you'd encounter some anti-aliasing artifacts there.

Comment: Unfortunately, upon zooming in further, the issue is still arising with a SVG format. It is not as noticeable but continues to exist.

Answer (score 0):

Based on an answer to a similar question ([ggplot2: blurry facet labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45821115/ggplot2-blurry-facet-labels)) you might be able to fix this by disabling antialiasing. Include

```
antialias="none"
```

in your ggsave line.