# Issues with adding a Line and arrow

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add a text, line and arrow to highlight a certain event in my plot. I followed the example I found and I do get an arrow and a line, however the quality looks very poor. The line should be smooth and the arrow sharp.

I'm using `annotate()` here for the line, the arrow and the text.

```
  annotate(
    "text", x="feb 2020", y=173000, label = "Text", vjust =1, size =4, col="#535353")+
  
  annotate(
    "curve", x="feb 2020", y=175000, xend="mrt 2020", yend=200000,
    arrow= arrow(length= unit(0.2, "cm"), type = "closed" ), col="#535353", curvature=-0.4, size=1
  )
```

I also tried using `geom_curve()` with similar settings, the result wasn't much better.

Thanks in advance!

[image][image]

Comment: This is very likely "just" a matter of how your device shows those lines, and related to anti-aliasing. Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6023179/7941188. Can you provide more information please: What device do you use? In more normal speech: Is this seen in your plot preview window, e.g., in RStudio, or is this the screenshot of a saved file, pdf or jpeg, or png...

Comment: Also important - do you use windows or Mac...

Comment: I agree with Tjebo that this is probably a device issue. Try to render the same plot with the `ragg` package and see if that helps, it specialises in anti-aliasing nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably depends on the device. Compare and contrast the default `png()` device on windows versus the `ragg::agg_png()` device. The latter has nicer anti-aliasing properties.

Dummy plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

plt <- ggplot() +
  geom_curve(aes(x = 1, y = 1, xend = 2, yend = 2),
             curvature = 0.2,
             arrow = arrow(type = "closed"))
```

The default windows png device:

```
png("default_windows.png", width = 200, height = 200)
print(plt)
dev.off()
```

[image]

With the ragg package:

```
ragg::agg_png("ragg_windows.png", width = 200, height = 200)
print(plt)
dev.off()
```

[image]